# Adding Rows to GridView Swallows Paging Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I've been writing an extension to grid view to add grouping rows to a gridview, by watching for when the desired item changes in the RowDataBoundEvent. So far it looks a little like this:

```
protected override void OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        object dataitem = args.Row.DataItem;

        string currentValue = dataitem.GetType().GetProperty(GroupingColumn).GetValue(dataitem, null).ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(previousValue) || currentValue != previousValue)
        {
            int currentRowIndex = args.Row.RowIndex + rowsAdded;
            int colspan = this.Columns.Count - 1;
            Label label = new Label { Text = currentValue, CssClass = "rowLabel" };
            TableCell cell = new TableCell { ColumnSpan = colspan, CssClass = "groupHeader" };
            GridViewRow newRow = new GridViewRow(currentRowIndex, currentRowIndex, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            cell.Controls.Add(label);                                   
            newRow.Cells.Add(cell);
            ((Table)args.Row.Parent).Controls.AddAt(currentRowIndex, newRow);

            previousValue = currentValue;
            rowsAdded++;
         }
     }

    base.OnRowDataBound(args);
}
```

The issue is that when I click a paging button, the paging event doesn't fire, and the extra rows added become empty rows. The page postbacks, and runs through page load etc, but never through the paging event. I have custom paging built into this extension as well, and the click event for my paging buttons doesn't fire either. It's not until the second click on the paging button that paging occurs.

I think this is happening because the paging row gets constructed before the rowdatabound event, during which paging buttons are created and their event handler's assigned. However, adding rows to the underlying table removes these handlers. Anyone have any idea how to ensure the custom paging buttons fire?

Edit 1: To clarify, adding to the data source then rebinding won't work, as there is no extra data to add. The effect I'm attempting to achieve is something like this:

|Group 1                      |

|Item 1   |Item 2   |Item 3   |

|Item 4   |Item 5   |Item 6   |

|Group 2                      |

|Item 7   |Item 8   |Item 9   |

Comment: It looks like you're adding rows to the grid but not to the data source when you yuor page_load fires, you rebind the grid to the 'old' data source and lose the values you've added.

Comment: I don't want to add rows to the data source, as there is no extra data to add. Instead the extra row acts as a group header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution on an answer to a similar question. The trick is to add rows in the PrepareControlHierarchy event. Also, make sure your row type is "Header", otherwise there can be some nasty side effects with custom paging.

See [Add Gridview Row AFTER Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685717/add-gridview-row-after-header/2421239#2421239)