# Add new row into Header of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with adding a new row with several controls like textBoxes into Header of GridView. When I add them into Header in GridView_RowCreated method with ...

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridViewRow r = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
```

.. they always are put into first row, not second. How can I change it? I want my created row put in second Header Row. 
I tried to do it by myself, Firstly, I modified ShowHeader into false and add both first and second rows programmatically, but it is wrong way, aspecially when grid has no data to show but it is necessary to show header. I found this discussion [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685717/add-gridview-row-after-header), but intellisence doesn't know about override PrepareControlHierarchy. I tried to search it with Object browser, and found that this is method of GridView, but I couldn't plug it and test. Maybe somebody knows easier solution for this prob. 
I need some assist.
**UPDATED!!!**
[image]

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="username" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

**UPDATED!!!!**
Yes, profs you are right, in my case it is the easiest way to put controls in HeaderTemplate. I forgot about it. But I have a little question, how can I add names of columns without adding additional Labels? Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="username" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField **HeaderText="username"** SortExpression="username">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                **<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="username"></asp:Label>**<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Surname"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

I marked bold strings. If I leave without Label (just with HeaderText="username") it isn't show me any name in header column. Only if I add Labels it shows my names. What is wrong with it?

Comment: why dont you create that inside headertemplate tag? can you show a snapshot of the requirement?

Comment: I created, and also I created some controls programmatically. Now I ahve a question how can I change places of headerstemplate row and my programmatically created row?

Comment: can you post your header template html markup?

Comment: I added markup, googling no help yet

Comment: Note that I answered before your edit, but my example shows how to accomplish your follow-up question. Simply put the label as inline text.

Comment: Yeah, it is work. Thanks. It is real the simplest way to solve this problem. But in theory, I would like to know how it is possible to do it from code-behind.

Comment: @mit: the scenario usually occurs when you have to merge rows too. take a look http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-Merging-GridView-Header-Columns-Cells-by-adding-Multiple-Headers-Header-Row-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically you would have to add a second header row after every has been databound

Example in VB but you should be able to convert it easily enough.

```
Private Sub GridView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound

    // Add checks for row count.

    // create a new row
    Dim gvr As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)

    Dim gvc As TableCell

    // Create a new empty cell
    gvc = New TableCell()

    //add a new TextBox to the cell
    gvc.Controls.Add(New TextBox())

    // Add the cell to the row
    gvr.Cells.Add(gvc)

    // repeat above as necessary

    // Add row to Gridview at index 1 (0 is bound header)
    // GridView1.Controls(0) is the Gridview table
    GridView1.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(1, gvr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to not attempt to do it in the code behind. Instead utilize the [HeaderTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your TemplateFields.

Here is one as an example:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username">
    <HeaderTemplate>                              
      username
      <br />
      <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" />
    </HeaderTemplate>   
    <ItemTemplate...   
</asp:TemplateField>
```